# authorizeResource for not logged-in users in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

While in policy class I have

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

but I get unauthorized error for unauthenticated users.

So how can I exclude the store method from authorization in authorizeResource?

Comment: Can you share your routes file?

Comment: @MEDZ There is nothing special in it: `Route::apiResource('companyregister' , 'CompanyRegisterController')->except('update');`

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: @Rwd Sorry, my mistake, i'm using laravel 6

Comment: Authorization requires a user so if there is no user you should not run the authorization at all.

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah the problem is all of other methods need the authorization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use guest users with Laravel's authorisation you simply need to type-hint that the user is nullable:

```
public function create(?User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

or you can set the default value to null

```
public function create(User $user = null)
{
    return true;
}
```

For more information you can check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#guest-users)

Comment: Interesting! I checked `public function create()` before and didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your route is located inside a group that forces auth middleware you just need to get it out of this group:

```
Route::post('company/create', 'CompanyController@create');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  //Your authenticated routes
  Route::apiResource('companyregister' , 'CompanyRegisterController')->except(['update', 'create']);
})
```